# How to get sum of value along with single value with whereIn clause in laravel/sql

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, union, laravel-query-builder

I am stuck, and can't find any solution.

| productId | shop.title | Qty | productName | rpId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Mark | 20 | Bread | 2 |
| 2 | John | 10 | Jame | 3 |
| 4 | Tonny | 5 | Eggs | 4 |
| 4 | Grey | 5 | Eggs | 5 |
| 15 | Boby | 25 | Bread | 6 |
| 4 | Ruby | 15 | Eggs | 7 |

```
$request->rpId = [3,4,8,9];
$purchaseOrders = DB::table('request_purchase_detail')
          ->join('request_purchase','request_purchase.id','=','request_purchase_detail.rpId')
            ->join('shop','shop.id','=','request_purchase.shopId')
            ->select('request_purchase_detail.productId', 'shop.title', 
           'request_purchase_detail.productQuantity as reqQty', 'request_purchase_detail.rpId', 
            DB::raw('sum(request_purchase_detail.productQuantity) as productQuantity'))
            ->whereIn('rpId',explode(",", $request->rpId ))
            ->get();
```

Explanation:

Let's Suppose I am making a purchase Order for all shop's required Items, and need the sum of total qty but at the same time I need individual too, i,e. Ruby required 7 packs of eggs.

My Query does not understand this

return sum of the qty i,e. 20 packs for eggs, but shop.title and individual shop required qty selected first one only i.e, Tonny required 4 packs of eggs.

Ruby required 7 packs of eggs OR Grey required 5 packs of eggs are not returning in that query.

Please try to understand my problem, Maybe I am a little bit stupid, just like my English.
But it's 5:00 AM here and you people are now my only Hope.

Comment: once you got the data of each returned item from the database, why don't you further filter from the returned collection!?

Comment: It is not necessary to take the sum in the query, because it will return as:
id:item1 - quantity: 1 - total: 10
id:item1 - quantity: 2 - total: 10
id:item3 - quantity: 3 - total: 10
id:item4 - quantity: 4 - total: 10